# How to solve the issue of JPEG live stream lagging?

Tags: c#, jpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, aforge

I have written C# code of live streaming of IP camera (JPEG) in windows form application using AForge library. It is working but it's lagging too much.

Here is the code:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using AForge.Video; 
namespace CCTV_software 
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 
        JPEGStream stream; 
        JPEGStream stream1; 
        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            stream = new JPEGStream("ip"); 
            stream1 = new JPEGStream("ip1"); 
stream.Login = "username"; 
stream.Password =  "password"; 
stream1.Login = "username1"; 
stream1.Password = "password1"; 
            stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame; 
            stream1.NewFrame += stream1_NewFrame1; 
            stream.Start(); 
            stream1.Start(); 
        } 
 
 
        void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) 
        { 
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); 
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;  
        } 
        void stream1_NewFrame1(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) 
        { 
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); 
            pictureBox2.Image = bp; 
        } 
    }
```

Tried adding:

```
stream.FrameInterval = 0;
```

But it didn’t made any difference.
Kindly help me out with this issue.

**Edit:**
[image: This is the error I'm getting]

**Edit 2:**
[image: This is what is displayed by clicking on view details]

[image: Here is the StackTrace]

Comment: Have you tried to set the Image directly without cloning?

Comment: I wonder if I'm placing ```stream.FrameInterval = 0; ``` in the right place. Do you know where in the code should it be placed for it to work?

Comment: _"What do you mean by that?"_ Instead of `Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); 
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` => `pictureBox1.Image = eventArgs.Frame;`

Comment: If you click on "View Details" there should be a stacktrace somewhere. Can you please add that?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, you can view the edit.

Comment: It's just a suspicion, but maybe the picturebox is trying to paint the disposed image... but I am really not sure. You could try to surround that part with SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout

Comment: Oh, it could be. Can you tell me how to surround it with suspendlayout/Resumelayout.? Sorry, I'm new to the field of coding.

Comment: I just checked, SuspendLayout may not be enough. Check my edit on the answer and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Okay. Let me try it out.

Comment: @Fildor I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Fildor I also wanna ask that ```stream.FrameInterval = 0;``` or ```stream.FrameIntrerval = 1000;``` is not making any difference. I doubt if I'm writing it down at the right place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

@mjwills and my suggestions combined:

```
void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) 
{
    var oldImage = pictureBox1.Image 
    pictureBox1.Image = eventArgs.Frame; // set to new image without making a copy
    oldImage?.Dispose(); // = Dispose previous image, if not null
}
```

This spares you a clone which is expensive and allows the gc to clean up the images timely.

Those measures combined should make it *possible* to improve throughput (i.e. lessen "lag"). Further countermeasures could be to make the image size smaller or reduce quality ...

NOTE: Above measures should at least *improve* lag, yet it is not guaranteed to make it disappear completely, since lag may be caused at other places, too.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try this out and let you know if it solved the problem or not.

Comment: I tried this out. It's giving an error **System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' ** on the line ```Application.Run(new Form1());``` in program.cs

Comment: That's really odd but I'd say it has nothing to do with the answer. Can you make sure, there is no brackets missing or something like that? Maybe clean and rebuild. [Run(Form)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Run_System_Windows_Forms_Form_) expects an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.Form` ... Check if you have squiggly red lines somewhere.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuild it. Double checked all the brackets. It runs and the camera starts but is not displayed on the screen. After 2 seconds error comes up.

Comment: Check Edit on my question. I've posted image of the error I'm getting.